# Get Collapsible div on the same line as <li>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, razor

On one of my company's websites we have the copyright notice at the bottom and I want to put a pipe character then a collapsible div for our Refund Policy.  It all works but the Refund Policy collapsible div keeps showing up below the copyright.  How can I get it on the same line?  This is my code:

```
<section id="footer">
    <div class="container inline-block">
        <ul class="copyright">
            <li>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() Securities Training Corporation. All rights reserved. |     
                <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                     <div class="panel-title">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Refund Policy</a>
                     </div>
                     <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                          <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" style="width: 580px" font-size="12">
                               <tr>
                                   <td>
                                       <br />
                                            <span>This is our Refund Policy in the collapsible div
                                   </td>
                               </tr>
                          </table>          
                      </div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
             </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

There is more code than this but it is irrelevant. I put the container in the same li tag.  Of course I only want the collapsible title to be on the same line as the copywrite.

Comment: By default, a div element will force a newline. What does your CSS look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to start by making your panel element `inline-block` (or give it an explicit width). The selector I'd use to target it with CSS would probably be:

```
#footer .copyright .panel-group {}
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0ttdp8ke/)**

Note that I've taken the width off the policy table. (Not sure why you're using a table for layout anyway.) Also, if you're using a list for your footer, put the individual information nodes in individual list items or don't use a list. It's confusing for screen-reader users otherwise.

**[Improved demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/0ttdp8ke/3)**

Comment: The reason I am using a table is I just copied the Refund Policy from another site we have and did not want to edit the formatting as much as I could.